# Cannot change authentication account on Logic Apps

Tags: azure, authentication, alias, devops, account

I am trying to build a logic app to email results of a devops query on a regular basis. When I use the 'Get query results' block in logic apps, I am unable to authenticate with my primary email address. Instead Logic Apps keeps picking up my alias email address when I try to change connection. No sign in screen is displayed so I assume my credentials are cached somewhere.

Any ideas on how I can change the account I use to login with?

***Update***

[image: Adding new connector]

Trying to add a new connector using 'add new'

[image: No option to sign in. Defaults to .uk account rather than using .co.uk account that I am signed into through Azure.]

No option to sign in. Defaults to .uk account rather than using .co.uk account that I am signed into through Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Under API Connections you can find any connections the Logic App is using. Click a connection to be able to edit or delete it.

[image: Logic App API Connections]

**EDIT:**
If you would like to use another email address instead of the current one, delete the connection and create a new one from the Logic Apps designer.

Comment: I can view the connection but not sure how to edit it. Need to add my .co.uk account rather than .uk account

Comment: You can delete it and create a new one from the Logic Apps designer

Comment: I too have the same issue of adding a new email connection but every time I try add the other email address it logs in with my address. I have tried chrome, edge and Firefox but cannot add a new connection. I am still blocked.